# Python - Remove duplicate in cell of datafeame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a column in datafrme structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Config': ['1A', '1A, 7A', '3C, 3C-7A', '1A, 3A, 1A-3A']})
print(df)

          Config
0             1A
1         1A, 7A
2      3C, 3C-7A
3  1A, 3A, 1A-3A
```

And if there is `XX-XX` in the cell, remove the duplicate previous item.
For instance, in row 2 and 3 will remove `3C`, `1A`, and `3A` (or create a new column):

```
   Config
0      1A
1  1A, 7A
2   3C-7A
3   1A-3A
```

Thanks a lot.

---

### Updated question:

original datadrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Config': ['1A', '1A, 7A', '3C, 3C-7A', '1A, 3A, 1A-3A', '5A, 3C-7A']})
df

          Config
0             1A
1         1A, 7A
2      3C, 3C-7A
3  1A, 3A, 1A-3A
4      5A, 3C-7A
```

target:

```
      Config
0         1A
1     1A, 7A
2      3C-7A
3      1A-3A
4  5A, 3C-7A
```

#### Explanation:

In row 2 and row 3:
    `3C` is duplicate to `3C-7A`
    `1A` and `3A` are duplicate to `1A-3A`
    so remove `3C`, `1A`, `3A`.

In row 4: 
    cause `5A` is not  duplicate the values in `3C-7A`, so both two value `5A` and  `3C-7A` retain.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. Please read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Comment: thanks for reminder, I'll noticed next time

Comment: Each 'cell' is a string, just the list thar you used to create the `df`,.  If you write a string processing function that returns a clean string, you can easily apply it the souse list (list comprehension) or to the cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data follow the same position then it will work for you,

```
df.loc[df['Config'].str.contains('-'),'Config']=df['Config'].str.split(',').str.get(-1)
```

Output:

```
   Config
0      1A
1  1A, 7A
2   3C-7A
3   1A-3A
```

Explanation:

It will split the values by `,` and took it's last value, where it has `-` in the series.

EDIT-1

```
print df['Config'].str.split(', |-').apply(set)

Output:

0            {1A}
1        {1A, 7A}
2        {3C, 7A}
3        {1A, 3A}
4    {3C, 5A, 7A}
```

Comment: is this having a check / making comparing the values?

Comment: @pygo - Sorry, I didn't get you

Comment: Does it make check within row for duplicates

Comment: @pygo - In this question a word called  `duplicate` refers old values. For example, `1A, 3A, 1A-3A` in this value `1A`, `3A` is duplicate because it has combination at next value as `1A-3A`. I hope you get cleared :-)

Comment: thanks, but futher more if there's other values how do I check comparing? sorry for some mistakes in my question, I'll updated.

Comment: @xiumpt - What value you want to compare? can you provide a sample. above snippet actually not comparing it's taking a last (latest) value.

Comment: @xiumpt - Can you check is this you are looking for?

Comment: As row 3, your first answer is matched. And in row 4, cause `5A` is not  duplicate the values in `3C-7A`, so I want both two value `5A` and  `3C-7A` retain. Sorry didn't make it clear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183929/discussion-between-mohamed-thasin-ah-and-xiumpt).